# On multiple roots in algebraic closure of a given field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, minimal-polynomials, algebraic-equations

I’m having trouble digesting a fact that popped up in a proof from Lang’s Algebra, page 247, proposition 6.1.
Given an element $\alpha$ algebraic over $k$, and its minimum polynomial $f(X)$ over k, Lang proves that (apparently not using the fact that f is irreducible) all roots of $f$ have equal multiplicity, regardless of the field’s characteristic.
This sounds funny, because it doesn’t seem to use any information other than the fact that the coefficients are all in $k$. Does this mean that any polynomial in Q will have roots of equal multiplicity in C?
I’m not sure whether I’m having trouble understanding the theory or if I’m not fishing enough examples for myself. I understand the proof, it’s just that I can’t seem to give myself enough heuristic motivation for this fact in particular.

Comment: Let $L$ be the splitting field of $f\in k[x]$ and $\alpha$ one of its roots and $\beta$ another root of $\alpha$'s minimal polynomial. Look at the isomorphism $\sigma:k(\alpha)\to k(\beta)$. The multiplicity of $\alpha$ in $f$ is the largest $m$ such that $f(x) = (x-\alpha)^m g(x)\in k(\alpha)[x]$, then applying $\sigma$ to the coefficients you get $f(x)=f^\sigma(x)=( (x-\alpha)^m)^\sigma g^\sigma(x)=(x-\beta)^m g^\sigma(x)$, do the same applying $\sigma^{-1}$ to the coefficients of $(x-\beta)^l h(x)$, you'll find that $\alpha,\beta$ have the same multiplicity.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Heuristically, would you say that this happens because, since you’ve shown it this way, $k(\alpha)$ and $k(\beta)$ are isomorphic? Thanks again

Comment: Yes it is because we have a $k$-algebra isomorphism $k(\alpha)[x]\to k(\beta)[x]$, this isomorphism follows from $k(\alpha)\cong k[y]/(P(y))$ where $P$ is the minimal polynomial, the same as for $\beta$.

Comment: I think I have a better understanding of this now, thank you again.